# List item's sub items covers whole list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve using css and javascript, when an initial list item is clicked the list item and the sub list will expand over to cover the list and only show the selected list item. If that makes sense.

https://jsfiddle.net/dj1xshzo/

at the moment ive created the list:

```
.nav ul li > ul{
  display:none;
}
.nav ul li.open > ul{
  display:block;
}
.nav ul {
  padding:0;
}
.nav ul li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
}
.nav > ul li{
  font-size:2em;
}
.nav > ul li > ul li{
  font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: CSS looks solid. What is your question?

Comment: @Geert-Jan is there a way with css and javascript to make the sublist display infront of the initial list

Comment: How would that work visually? Should the other top-level items just be collapsed / hidden? If so, simply hiding all other top-level items using JS would suffice. Not sure if this works nicely from a UX perspective though.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/gfruwbfg/ for something rough as per above